# Logging client time drift on an ntpd server

Tags: linux, ntp

I need to verify that a whole bunch of computers are within 50ms of ntp or nist time. Currently some are windows some are linux, and the windows machines are syncing with a domain controller that is pointed to ntp time, and each linux server is synced to a ntp pool server. Time does not seem to be a problem, but I need to prove it.

Any suggestions on methods to do this? I was hoping ntpd had some sort of logging capability, and that I could direct clients to query it and it then record the drift. I'd prefer it didn't act as authoritative time server, but just as a record keeper.

Comment: `ntp` has pretty extensive logging capabilities - all pretty well documented on the main NTP web site. What you might be looking for, though is just `ntptrace` or `ntpq` - they can query individual machines and tell you how far they are offset from their up-strata neighbors, as well as other useful information. That's easier than parsing through the logs...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a script to capture the values from ntpq and graph them in MRTG with RRD Tool.

The image below is taken from one of my Linux boxes - is that the sort of thing you are after? If you can provide some more info, and what OS the boxes you want to monitor are using I'll see if I can point you in the direction of the script I used, and provide some MRTG & RRD specific configs. My setup works on linux boxes only at the moment - and I've not had time to do any testing with Windows etc. If you where to adapt my solution to windows it would almost certainly require ntpd & ntpq rather than the standard Windows time client (as I don't believe you can get the sort of data you need from it).

[image: MRTG Plot of NTP offset]

Within ntpd.conf you can also enable `statistics loopstats` which will log data. You should check the ntpd documentation [here](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/index.html) for more info.